# Python Gaussian elimination with for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, vectorization

I'm trying to write code to carry out Gaussian elimination on a matrix using for loops rather than vectorisation. My code is as follows:

```
def myGaussJordan(A,m): 
    """
    Perform Gauss Jordan elimination on A.

    A: a square matrix.
    m: the pivot element is A[m, m].
    Returns a matrix with the identity matrix 
    on the left and the inverse of A on the right. 
    """
    B = np.column_stack((A,np.identity(m)))
    C = B
    for i in range(0,m):
        B[i,] = B[i,]/B[i,i]
        tmp = list(range(0,m))
        tmp.remove(i) ## remove the row since we only operate on other rows
        for j in tmp:
            for k in range(0,(2*m)):
                B[j,k] =  C[j,k] - C[i,k]*(C[j,i]/C[i,i])
        C = B

## Function returns the np.array B
    return B
```

I need C so that the row operations are tracked in the right hand side of B, to generate the inverse matrix. Running through the debugger it seems that the first "k" loop works as intended, but then once C =B, Python updates C and B simultaneously in the subsequent code leading to errors.

Also I note that I vectorised the k loop, and the identical code worked fine. Also i ran this same method coded up in R, and it works, so I am very confused.

Am i missing something with Python's assignment of variables or indentations?

Comment: I seem to have solved this by adding yet another for loop into set C to B elementwise. Not sure why this makes any difference?  Suppose  I set x=1, y=1 and x=y. and then set x =4, y wouldn't change, so I'm not sure why I ran into this issue!

Comment: See if this helps out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483704/